# How to find a short URL for an Azure DevOps Wiki page?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

Is there any built-in way to share a page in an Azure DevOps project's wiki with a short URL or slug?

Using the URL shown in the browser location bar is not very memorable or readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [azdo.io](https://azdo.io/), it gives Azure DevOps (a.k.a. AzDO) short, beautiful and memorable URLs with no effort.

How it works:

- Install the [browser extension](http://browser.azdo.io/) from the Chrome store.
- Navigate to a build, release, work item or wiki page in your AzDO project.
- Click the AzDO linkinator icon icon in the browser toolbar.

[image]

For example, the following Wiki URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/[ORG]/[PROJECT]/_wiki/wikis/[ORG]/[PROJECT].wiki?pagePath=%2FSome%2FSubfolder%2FPage
```

Will be:

```
http://wiki.azdo.io/Some/Subfolder/Page
```

Comment: Not exactly built in, but it worked for my present case. Built in support for short, beautiful and memorable URLs would still be nice since for some of my customers policy will preclude using a public service for this.

Comment: You can request a feature here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea